# Download from software center fails

Tags: 11.10, software-center, internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix 'Check your Internet connection' error in software center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77487/how-to-fix-check-your-internet-connection-error-in-software-center)

what should i do? in ubuntu 11.10 when im trying to dl something from USC it says check your internet connection while im online!!! & then it says "Requires installation of untrusted packages" !!!
what should i do?

Comment: Can you make system updates? What happensif you try to install the same package via a console with the command `sudo apt-get install packagename`?

Comment: when i try to install by update manager it again says:"Requires installation of untrusted packages

The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources."

Comment: execute in terminal `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and update your post with this information....

Comment: a lot of thanks to "hhlp" sudo apt-get update Worked & the USC is working well!

Comment: @hhlp please take your comment to be the actual answer since it fully solved the problem.

Comment: +1 I have the same problem. Internet connection works, but I can't download applications from Software Center.